# Wayona wifi adapter installation for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless

I am trying to install WAYONA WYN-12 Mini USB adapter drivers for LInux / Ubuntu 18.04. The CD contents are instruction less and gives absolutely no idea what to do with the content. Also I tried the following solution posted a lot of time ago but now it is asking for 'username' and 'password'.

```bash
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601u.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

Following is the output of lsusb with the WiFi adapter plugged:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` with the dongle inserted.

Comment: Who "it" is asking for username and password?

Comment: @Pilot6 : by 'it' i mean the git clone.

Comment: This means that this repo is made private. You can't clone it.

Comment: What is the kernel version? `uname -a`?

Comment: This adapter should be supported without any additional drivers.

Comment: Understood. But is there any alternate way to solve the issue. I searched a lot but the same repo is referenced everywhere. P.S .: I am a newbie (2 days) in Ubuntu

Comment: Kernel version: Linux hp 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This repo is very old. It was made when the device wasn't supported. Now it has been removed.

Comment: Does the adapter work?

Comment: Yes, the adapter seems to work. But the issue I am facing is it is still dependent on the inbuilt WiFi drivers of the laptop i.e., both the adapter and laptop is getting connected to WiFi and if I turn off one any of them both get shut down.

Comment: Then write a new question explaining the real problem. You don't need any drivers anyway.

Comment: I want my laptop to get connected via the adapter only as I am quite sure the weak and fluctuating strength of WIFi is due to the inbuilt component.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time and attention @Pilot6

Comment: This adapter is not really good. I don't think that is the reason. But you can disable built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

This wireless device `148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter` is natively supported by Linux kernel.

You don't need any 3rd party drivers for it.

The git repo you mentioned is obsolete and not available any more.